# Newport has no costs on UK PowerGrid map - A misprint?

Tags: power-grid

On the **UK & Ireland / Northern Europe** expansion map, the town of Newport has no `10 15 20` pricing.  The Expansion rules sheet makes no mention of this place having any special meaning.

I assume this is simply a misprint rather than that these sites are 'free' to occupy.

Is this a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a misprint. [From the game publisher](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/920143/newport-on-british-map):

> Oh, that is a misprint. As far as I can check this, all three numbers
>   are missing in Newport. Of course this city should have the same
>   numbers as all normal cities (10/15/20).
>
> Sorry!
>
> Henning (2F-Spiele)